# Clone from Atlassian Stash/BitBucket using custom SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Preserving the answer for future generations

I have a script that needs to clone a repo held in Stash. The repo does not have public access turned on (and we can't due to internal policies). I have generated a new SSH key pair for this script to use, and have stored the public key in the "Access Keys" part of the repo's config in Stash. The keys are not stored in my user .ssh dir (they are not in ~/.ssh), but are in a .ssh dir local to the script ( script_home/.ssh, with the right ownership and file permissions)

What is the git command, that uses the local keys, to clone the repo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /path/to/script/.ssh/id_rsa' git clone ssh://git@host:port/project/reponame.git
```

You need to use an absolute path in the -i option, I have found.

You can use ssh-add too if you don't like the GIT_SSH_COMMAND setting before the git command

```
ssh-add /path/to/script/.ssh/some_private_key
git clone ssh://git@host:port/project/reponame.git
```

Not that Stash seems to slightly modify URLS when using SSH or HTTPS. The matching HTTPS URL is

```
https://actual.user@host:port/scm/project/repo.git
```

Don't get caught like me and have that '**/scm/**' part of the HTTPS URI, in SSH URI

Note also how this differs from Github.

When using SSH

```
git clone git@github.com:some_user/some_repo.git
```

The SSH protocol part of the URL is missing completely.

When using HTTPS

```
git clone https://github.com/some_user/some_repo.git
```

And the HTTPS protocol is present for this case.